# Is it bad practice to write to files in your application's .app folder?

Tags: macos

Is it bad practice to write to files in your application's .app folder on MacOS? I want the user to be able to delete the app and configs via drag and drop from Applications folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is bad practice, for a number of reasons:

- macOS is a multi-user OS, and in general each user should have their own preferences, settings, etc.
- Users generally don't (and shouldn't) have file permissions to modify things in /Applications. If an admin user manually installed an app via drag-and-drop, they will have write access to it, but this can't be counted on (especially since, as I said, it's a multi-user OS and a different user may've installed it).
- If your app is code-signed, changes in the app container will break the signature and the app will refuse to open (it's considered damaged). Even it you don't sign it, the OS may apply an ad-hoc signature to it (for various reasons), and modifications will break *that*.